# How to provide KeyPress event to WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net

i really need to catch "ESC" key press while focus is on WebBrowser control.
I tried something like this:

```
(webControl as Control).KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(MyKeyPressEventHandler);
```

But it doesnt work. The method is not called. I tried some methods, described here, but dont get any result ( Help, please.

Comment: I believe you need to use javascript to do this, take a look at this link and see if it helps you out. [Get Key Press Event Using JavaScript from GeekPedia.com](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial138_Get-key-press-event-using-JavaScript.html)

Comment: Oh... I'd like to, but this is desctop aplication, and I dont know how to inject script into each page, that have been opened in WebBrowser control (standart control).

Comment: I'm assuming that you tried the PreviewKeyDown event that the WebBrowser control already has and that it isn't doing what you need, but I just wanted to confirm that before I look into this more

Answer (score 2):

```
this.webBrowser.Document.Body.KeyUp += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Body_KeyUp);
```